# Perl6 is now known as Raku

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21251666

[perl6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl6) should be renamed to [raku](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raku) and existing postings should be re-tagged. SO did this already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with this, and it should be done. I started the process by creating the raku tag, but then ran out of privileges to complete it (I don't have enough perl6 tag-rep to complete the synonym.

The tag should be created [raku](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raku) and then existing [perl6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl6) questions should be merged in to [raku](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raku), and then [perl6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl6) should be synonym-linked to [raku](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raku). This will likely need moderator privileges to do.

**Update**:

I have checked and edited all [perl6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl6) questions and added the [raku](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raku) tag to them. All that needs doing is a moderator, or enough [perl6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl6) high-rep users to create the synonym....

Comment: Tags have been merged/synonymized, thanks!